# Units in XE7 take to long to open

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I just start to use Delphi XE7

Some project just take to long to open.

One of the projects is still in D2007, but others are in XE2.

They are not to big, just basic Tforms, or TDatamodules.

I have search in Google for both this and general problems with XE7 and nothing pops up.

In the simple tests I have done, opening the separate unit out of the project, take some extra time but opens. But opening the same unit in the project may take hours, and if it is the projects main unit its impossible to open the all project.

Just don't know what to do next.
As this append to any one ?

Comment: This sounds strange, like if you have remote paths on your search path that are no longer available or are very slow to access. You may want to run Delphi XE7 under [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) and try to see there where all that time is spent.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error. No path. All units are local, and in subFolders.

Comment: The forms that take time to open, have datasets? Does a form without datasets takes time as well?

Comment: @DanieleTeti. Yes on both situation I have a dataset on both TForm and TDataModule.